# Does not contain a definition for and no extension method accepting a first argument of type could be found

Tags: c#, betfair

I've looked around at some of the solutions to this problem but they don't seem to be the same as what I'm experiencing.

Method that I'm trying to call:

```
namespace BetfairAPI
{
    public class CBetfairAPI
    {
        public ArrayList placeBets(ArrayList betList, double stakeSize)
        {
            // code to betList maniplulate

            return betList;
        }
    }
}
```

Method that I'm calling from:

```
namespace Bot
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
            private void makeBets(MarketSummary mkt, double odds, double stakeAmt)
            {
                ArrayList betList = new ArrayList();

                // code to build "betList"

                ArrayList bets = MyBetfair.placeBets(betList, stakeAmt);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error that I'm receiving:

> Error 1   'BetfairAPI.CBetfairAPI' does not contain a definition for
>   'placeBets' and no extension method 'placeBets' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'BetfairAPI.CBetfairAPI' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have no problem using any other methods in the CBetfairAPI class. placeBets() doesn't show up in the drop down menu in Visual studio if I do 'CBetfairAPI.' (all the other methods and fields do).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where and how is declared the variable `MyBetfair`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`placeBets(betList, stakeAmt)` is an *instance* method not a *static* method. You need to create an instance of `CBetfairAPI` first:

```
MyBetfair api = new MyBetfair();
ArrayList bets = api.placeBets(betList, stakeAmt);
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare an instance of the CBetfairAPI class or make it static.

Answer (score 2):

There are two cases in which this error is raised.

1. You didn't declare the variable which is used
2. You didn't create the instances of the class

Comment: Though these are both helpful, it's good to make it clear what you think the OP's particular problem is. In this case, it looks like the accepted answer has already solved the problem (as this is quite an old question). But in future, it's best if the answer you post comes to a full solution, not just highlights possible ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `this` keyword in your `placeBets` method.
To my understanding, you can use `this` to create an extension method for a given type. In this case, you are creating an extension method for Arraylists.

```
public static ArrayList placeBets(this ArrayList betList, double stakeSize)
{
    return betList;
}
```