# How do I print 1 column from a list

Tags: c#

So I have this code in `Game.cs`:

```
public string _type { get; }
public int _strength;

public Game(string charType, int strength) {
  this._type = charType;
  this._strength = strength;
}
public override string ToString() {
  return $"{_type} {_strength}";
}
```

And I have this code in `Program.cs`:

```
List<Game> JoinLists = new List<Game>();
JoinLists.Add(new Game("Elf", 6));
JoinLists.Add(new Game("Angel", 10));
JoinLists.Add(new Game("Demon", 10));
JoinLists.Add(new Game("Wizard", 9));
JoinLists.Add(new Game("Undead", 7));
JoinLists.Add(new Game("Vampire", 9));
JoinLists.Add(new Game("Troll", 6));
Console.WriteLine("This is the last of characters that are owned by you: ");
List<Character> chars = BusinessLayer.Instance.GetAllCharacters();

foreach(var character in JoinLists) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(character.charType);
    foreach (Character c in chars) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c.Health);
    }
}
```

I just want to print the `charType`. Any way I can do that please?

I get this error:

> 'Game' does not contain a definition for and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type 'Game' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Hello! The assembly reference error you are getting sounds pretty important. Please include the error, as it is likely related to build configurations and not the actual code that you provided.

Comment: What is the entire error message?  What assembly are you missing?

Comment: @h0r53 Ok I put the error in the post

Comment: Are Game and Program in the same project?  What namespace is each one in?

Comment: @Amy yes they are. I am able to print the list entirely in program I just need to print the chartype

Comment: To be able to get the chracter type you'd have to expose it like `public string Type {get;}` then use that instead of `_type` (which I assume is private).

Comment: That error message means the compiler is failing to build the type `Game`. Did u create the full class for `Game`?

Comment: Is the first code snippet enclosed in `public class Game { ... }` or just stand alone?

Comment: The code you provided seems incomplete. For one, you reference `character.charType` but the `Game` class stores that data as `_type`, not `charType`, which is an argument in your constructor. Please provide all relevant code.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066556/does-not-contain-a-definition-for-and-no-extension-method-accepting-a-first-argu

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes yes it is enclosed in public class Game

Comment: @gerryc.inc The error indicates the OP is trying to use a member of `Game` that it doesn't have, not that they cannot build the `Game` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the code you've provided is complete, there is an error on the following line:

```
Console.WriteLine(character.charType);
```

As the `Game` class is defined, the desired data is stored as the variable `_type`, not `charType`. Thus, change the line above to the following is see if that resolves your error.

```
Console.WriteLine(character._type);
```